# What does this mean "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" in plugins/gravityforms/form_display.php

Tags: gravityforms

I have this error message, "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" that's in gravity form in `form_display.php`.

I tried to look online for solutions but I can't find much. Some said it has to do with php while other didn't offer solutions at all.

So I'm asking what does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: same here, happens after I updated php version to 7.4 (host is forcing me). Not sure yet where it comes from, disabled all other plugins, nothing changes. Errors move away if I disable gravityform comlpetely (obviously).